# Can we render a html file to any card in Bot Framework

Tags: botframework, adaptive-cards

I'm trying to find a way to render HTML markup as the content of a Bot Framework adaptive card. Is this possible? If not can I do it using any other cards like Hero, Thumbnail, etc?

Answer (score 4):

No, adaptive-cards have their own json schema and html is not part of it.  None of the bot framework supported channels (including WebChat) currently support html rendering.

If you need html support in WebChat, this blog post discusses how to enable it: https://blog.botframework.com/2017/09/07/html-not-supported-web-chat/